# How to run mkfs on a BD-RE in linux

Tags: filesystems, mkfs, burning, blu-ray, optical-media

```
~ # mkfs.btrfs /dev/sr0
btrfs-progs v6.3.3
See https://btrfs.readthedocs.io for more information.

ERROR: '/dev/sr0' is too small to make a usable filesystem
ERROR: minimum size for each btrfs device is 114294784


~ # df -h /dev/sr0
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
```

Gentoo Wiki said MAYBE I had to do this, so I did. (the wording is very unclear). It had no effect.

```
~ # dvd+rw-format /dev/sr0
* BD/DVD�RW/-RAM format utility by <appro@fy.chalmers.se>, version 7.1.
* 25.0GB BD media detected.
* formatting 75.0/
```

This worked, but the resulting filesystem is only 7.7 megabytes in size.

```
~ # mkfs.ext4 /dev/sr0
mke2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Creating filesystem with 5270 2k blocks and 2640 inodes

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (1024 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

~ # mkdir /media/optical
~ # mount -t ext4 /dev/sr0 /media/optical
~ # df -h /media/optical
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sr0        7.7M   20K  6.9M   1% /media/optical
```